# Help find a proof : $ \lambda $ is $f$'s eigenvalue then $f|_{V_{\lambda}} $ has Jordan's basis

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Could you help me find a fairly simple proof of the following theorem?

$f: V \rightarrow V, \ \ \dim V < \infty, \ \ \lambda$ is $f$'s eigenvalue $\Rightarrow \ \ f|_{V_{\lambda}}: \ V_{\lambda} \rightarrow V_{\lambda}$ has Jordan's basis.

Comment: How, then, are you defining $V_\lambda$? As $\{v \in V \mid \exists k \in \mathbb{N}, \; (f-\lambda 1_V)^k v = 0\}$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It is $ \{v \in V \mid \exists k \in \mathbb{N}, \; (f-\lambda $ id $)^k v = 0\}$

Comment: The key is to show that if $v \in V_\lambda$, and if $k$ is the least number such that $(f-\lambda 1_V)^kv = 0$, then $\{(f-\lambda 1_V)^i \}_{i=0}^{k-1}$ is linearly independent.